# Scrolling issue in IOS Safari

Tags: html, css, ios, reactjs, safari

I have this code:

```
<div style="height: calc(100vh - 200px); overflow: hidden auto;">
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
  <div class="item">test</div>
</div>
```

Element scrolling is not working only for Safari mobile (IOS). It looks like overflow hidden styles, but I inspected Safari and all styles applied like in other devices. So everything maybe okay with styles, but it does not work and I don't know why.

I tried many CSS hacks to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. It's came from IOS version. After IOS updating this issue was fixed. So it's not code level bug.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still experiencing this issue and the above hasn't helped check if you have a **"position: relative"** on the body or html tag and **remove it**. This was the issue scrolling was broken on safari mobile for me.